# MySQL - Optimize Query To Remove Using Temporary and Using filesort

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-optimization, filesort

### Query

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE
 `Table1`.`recordID`
FROM
  `Table1`
  LEFT JOIN `Table3` ON `Table3`.`table1RecordID`=`Table1`.`recordID`
WHERE
  (`Table3`.`status` = '3' OR `Table3`.`status` = '4')  AND
  (`Table1`.`groupName` = 'Sample Name')
GROUP BY `Table3`.`recordID` ASC, `Table1`.`recordID` ASC;
```

### Explain

```
+----+-------------+--------+--------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table  |  type  |        possible_keys         |   key   | key_len |             ref              | rows  |                    Extra                     |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table3 | ALL    | fk_packageID,regStatus,pkgID | NULL    | NULL    | NULL                         | 11322 | Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | Table1 | eq_ref | PRIMARY,groupName            | PRIMARY | 4       | testDb.Table3.table1RecordID |     1 | Using where                                  |
+----+-------------+--------+--------+------------------------------+---------+---------+------------------------------+-------+----------------------------------------------+
```

---

If I remove the second part of the GROUP BY, "`Table1`.`recordID` ASC" but data isn't correct when I do that. Why is it doing this and how can I fix it and still group down by Table1 in addition to the Table3 first.

Thanks in advanced!

## Update 1/24/14

I had time to take the full query and pull the tables to a generic form to post without client data. I was able to add schema to sqlfiddle but without the data I'm using results can be different and I was even unable to put 100 rows pre-table (7 total) into sqlfiddle due to limitations of characters. So instead I've done a dump of the tables and I'm sharing it over dropbox.

### Dropbox

https://www.dropbox.com/s/9fgu626996utpar/stackoverflow-21291707_test_db_schema_and_data.sql

### Query

```
SELECT
  `t1`.`name` AS `Object1.Name`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  IF(`t5`.`questionID`=68,
    IF(`t6`.`writeInRequired` = 1,
      CONCAT(
        `t6`.`value`,
        ':', `t5`.`writeInResponse`
      ),
      `t6`.`value`
    ),
    NULL
  ) SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Object3.Response_68`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  IF(`t5`.`questionID`=67,
    IF(`t6`.`writeInRequired` = 1,
      CONCAT(
        `t6`.`value`,
        ':', `t5`.`writeInResponse`
      ),
      `t6`.`value`
    ),
    NULL
  ) SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Object3.Response_67`,
  GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
  IF(`t5`.`questionID`=66,
    IF(`t6`.`writeInRequired` = 1,
      CONCAT(
        `t6`.`value`,
        ':', `t5`.`writeInResponse`
      ),
      `t6`.`value`
    ),
    NULL
  ) SEPARATOR ', ') AS `Object3.Response_66`,
  `t7`.`firstName` AS `Object8.FirstName`,
  `t7`.`lastName` AS `Object8.LastName`,
  `t7`.`email` AS `Object8.Email`,
  `t1`.`recordID` AS `Object1.PackageID`,
  `t3`.`recordID` AS `Object5.RegistrationID`
FROM
  `Table1` t1
  LEFT JOIN `Table2` t2 ON `t1`.`recordID`=`t2`.`table1RecordID`
  LEFT JOIN `Table3` t3 ON `t3`.`table1RecordID`=`t1`.`recordID`
  LEFT JOIN `Table4` t4 ON `t4`.`table3RecordID`=`t3`.`recordID` AND `t4`.`type` = 1
  LEFT JOIN `Table5` t5 ON `t5`.`objectID`=`t3`.`recordID` AND `t5`.`objectType`='Type2'
  LEFT JOIN `Table6` t6 ON `t6`.`recordID`=`t5`.`table6RecordID`
  JOIN `Table7` t7 ON `t7`.`recordID`=`t4`.`table7RecordID`
WHERE
  `t3`.`status` IN ('3','4')
GROUP BY
  `Object5.RegistrationID` ASC,
  `Object1.PackageID` ASC
```

### EXPLAIN EXTENDED (/G)

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t7
         type: ALL
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: NULL
      key_len: NULL
          ref: NULL
         rows: 11627
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t4
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_table7RecordID,idx_table3RecordID
          key: idx_table7RecordID
      key_len: 5
          ref: testDb.t7.recordID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 3. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t3
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY,table1RecordID_status,idx_status,idx_table1RecordID
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: testDb.t4.table3RecordID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using where
*************************** 4. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t5
         type: ref
possible_keys: compositeIDs
          key: compositeIDs
      key_len: 773
          ref: const,testDb.t3.recordID
         rows: 5
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra:
*************************** 5. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t6
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: testDb.t5.table6RecordID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra:
*************************** 6. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t1
         type: eq_ref
possible_keys: PRIMARY
          key: PRIMARY
      key_len: 4
          ref: testDb.t3.table1RecordID
         rows: 1
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra:
*************************** 7. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: t2
         type: ref
possible_keys: idx_table1RecordID
          key: idx_table1RecordID
      key_len: 5
          ref: testDb.t1.recordID
         rows: 85
     filtered: 100.00
        Extra: Using index
7 rows in set, 1 warning (0.13 sec)
```

### EXPLAIN EXTENDED (ASCII TABLE)

```
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table |  type  |                        possible_keys                        |        key         | key_len |           ref            | rows  | filtered |              Extra              |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t7    | ALL    | PRIMARY                                                     | NULL               | NULL    | NULL                     | 11627 | 100.00   | Using temporary; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t4    | ref    | idx_table7RecordID,idx_table3RecordID                       | idx_table7RecordID | 5       | testDb.t7.recordID       |     1 | 100.00   | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t3    | eq_ref | PRIMARY,table1RecordID_status,idx_status,idx_table1RecordID | PRIMARY            | 4       | testDb.t4.table3RecordID |     1 | 100.00   | Using where                     |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t5    | ref    | compositeIDs                                                | compositeIDs       | 773     | const,testDb.t3.recordID |     5 | 100.00   |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t6    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                     | PRIMARY            | 4       | testDb.t5.table6RecordID |     1 | 100.00   |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t1    | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                     | PRIMARY            | 4       | testDb.t3.table1RecordID |     1 | 100.00   |                                 |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | t2    | ref    | idx_table1RecordID                                          | idx_table1RecordID | 5       | testDb.t1.recordID       |    85 | 100.00   | Using index                     |
+----+-------------+-------+--------+-------------------------------------------------------------+--------------------+---------+--------------------------+-------+----------+---------------------------------+
```

Thanks again in advanced!

### For @Strawberry

Removed select clauses and just select the recordID of the first table. This query still produces the same explain from above.

```
SELECT
  `t1`.`recordID`
FROM
  `Table1` t1
  LEFT JOIN `Table2` t2 ON `t1`.`recordID`=`t2`.`table1RecordID`
  LEFT JOIN `Table3` t3 ON `t3`.`table1RecordID`=`t1`.`recordID`
  LEFT JOIN `Table4` t4 ON `t4`.`table3RecordID`=`t3`.`recordID` AND `t4`.`type` = 1
  LEFT JOIN `Table5` t5 ON `t5`.`objectID`=`t3`.`recordID` AND `t5`.`objectType`='Type2'
  LEFT JOIN `Table6` t6 ON `t6`.`recordID`=`t5`.`table6RecordID`
  JOIN `Table7` t7 ON `t7`.`recordID`=`t4`.`table7RecordID`
WHERE
  `t3`.`status` IN ('3','4')
GROUP BY
  `t3`.`recordID` ASC,
  `t1`.`recordID` ASC;
```

Comment: Why do you have a GROUP BY at all? Also, this is rendered as an INNER JOIN because of the WHERE condition on the joined table

Comment: I think you should start again, with proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) TOGETHER WITH THE DESIRED RESULT SET.

Comment: @Strawberry I'll see what I can do. The data behind it is too large for sqlfiddle sadly.

Comment: Er, so provide less data!?! Also, fwiw, I like to do `explains` with `\G` rather than `;`

Comment: @Strawberry I tried to reduce data but sqlfiddle with the number of tables wouldn't even accept 50 rows per-table. So instead I've updated the question with a full query and a SQL file on dropbox.

Comment: You seem to think that this is a question about performance, but I'm not so sure. Instead, i think it's a question about proper design, and writing elegant queries. Once these are right, tweaking indexes is (relatively) straightforward. Incidentally, I'm increasingly convinced that GROUP_CONCAT is a poor  function, performing a task that is generally best left to presentation layer code.

Comment: @Strawberry The query is generated from code that lets users create a report on data. So I'm working on improving that. As far as GROUP_CONCAT, even if you take out all the select clauses and have 1 single clause for say `Table`.`recordID` it still take forever to process the query (I believe it was taking 20-30 minutes to finish) which obviously is due to the filesort and temporary tables it's using. So if you want to look at the query without the select clause please do as it still produces the exact same EXPLAIN results and still performs extremely poor. Thanks.

Comment: For clarity, can you update your question to show the simplified SELECT too?

Comment: OK... Did you understand the point about t3 being an inner join? And all the 'record_ids' are indexed, right?

Comment: @Strawberry So the t3 being a LEFT JOIN is being treated as an INNER JOIN because of the WHERE clause (t3.status IN ())? All "recordID" columns on each table are PRIMARY KEY and auto increment .

Comment: So (and this isn't my strength) the only scope for optimisation I can see is a composite index on (t4.table3recordid,t4.type). Probably not much help.

Answer (score 0):

Some comments about your query:

1. The Left outer join is unnecessary.  You are undoing the outer join with the `where` clause.
2. There is no need to group by both fields, `Table1`.`recordID` is sufficient.
3. `in` is more readable than a bunch of comparisons with `or`.

Here is the resulting query:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t1.`recordID`
FROM `Table1` t1 JOIN
     `Table3` t3
     ON t3.`table1RecordID` = t1.`recordID`
WHERE t3.`status` in ('3', '4')  AND
      t1.`groupName` = 'Sample Name'
GROUP BY t1.`recordID` ASC;
```

Does this perform better?

If not, let's think about what the query is doing.  It is trying to filter out records from `t1` based on things in `t3`.  Assuming that `table1.RecordId` is unique, then this would work:

```
SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE t1.`recordID`
FROM `Table1` t1 
WHERE t1.`groupName` = 'Sample Name' and
      exists (select 1
              from Table3 t3
              where t3.`status` in ('3', '4') and
                    t1.RecordId = t3.RecordId
             );
```

For best performance, you should have an index on `Table3(RecordId, status)`.

Comment: First query works with some index changes (Table3 (table1RecordID, status)). But I wanted to join an additional table which is adding this: "LEFT JOIN Table5 t5 ON t5.`objectID`=t3.`recordID` AND t5.`objectType` = 'SampleObject'" causes it go to back to using filesort again.

Comment: I've updated the question with the full query as I thought originally narrow it down to where things looked to go arise would be where to start but once you optimized that and I tried to add the rest more went arise. So check out the full query I'm working with and I've attached the SQL dump on dropbox. Thanks in advanced.